# SQL Server - Optimize window functions w/out repeating code?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have one table on which I want to perform some calculations.  The table stores employee points that are awarded for performing various tasks.  The relevant structure is as follows (table has about 15,000 rows):

```
PointsTable:

  ID int IDENTITY(1, 1),
  EmployeeFirstName (varchar),
  EmployeeLastName (varchar),
  PointsAwarded (decimal(18, 2)),
  TransactionDate (date)
```

For each row, I want to return the following:

```
Employee Name
Points Awarded
Transaction Date
Employee's Running Total (cumulative sum for that one employee)
Employee's Total Points (sum of all points for that one employee)
Running Total (cumulative sum for all employees)
Total Points (sum of all points for all employees)
Employee's Running Percentage (Employee's Running Total / Employee's Total Points)
Employees' Total Percentage (Employee's Total Points / Total Points)
Total Running Percentage (Running Total / Total Points)
```

Here is the query I am currently using:

```
SELECT  EmployeeFirstName + ' ' + EmployeeLastName AS [Employee], 
        PointsAwarded, 
        TransactionDate, 
        [Employee Running Total], 
        [Employee Running Total] / [Employee Total Points] AS [Employee Running Percentage],
        [Employee Total Points],
        [Employee Total Points] / [Total Points] AS [Employee Total Percentage],
        [Running Total Points], 
        [Running Total Points] / [Total Points] AS [Total Running Percentage],
        [Total Points]
FROM 
    (
    SELECT  EmployeeFirstName, 
            EmployeeLastName, 
            PointsAwarded, 
            TransactionDate,
            SUM(PointsAwarded) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeFirstName, EmployeeLastName ORDER BY ID) AS [Employee Running Total],
            SUM(PointsAwarded) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeFirstName, EmployeeLastName) AS [Employee Total Points],
            SUM(PointsAwarded) OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS [Running Total Points],
            SUM(PointsAwarded) OVER() AS [Total Points]
    FROM PointsTable
    ) t
```

This query works and returns the results as expected.  However, I feel like it can be optimized.  Is it possible to include the calculations within the sub query, without repeating code?

For example, this code is necessary to give the Employee Running Percentage:

```
SUM(PointsAwarded) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeFirstName, EmployeeLastName ORDER BY ID) / 
SUM(PointsAwarded) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeFirstName, EmployeeLastName)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with windowing - WITHOUT repeating the OVER functions a bunch of times?  So far, the only way I've been able to achieve this is in the manner I've posted.  I'm thinking a CTE would be more or less the same, but I'm not an expert.

Thanks in advance for your help - and please let me know if I can clarify in any way.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server

Comment: Your code is fine.  Let the optimizer optimize the code.  I wouldn't use the subquery, but that has nothing to do with performance, just code verbosity.

Comment: Thanks, you two.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, so you would prefer to repeat the OVER functions?  To me, it looks messier and is more difficult to read - so I used the subquery purely for readability/neatness.  Is that a flawed approach?

Comment: I Coundn't think of writing differently, because it looks effective. Try and run execution plan and take it from there

Comment: @StanShaw . . . (1) SQL Server doesn't have a way of declaring window references (Postgres, by contrast, does).  (2) The window specifications are different -- the order by significantly changes the meaning of the expression.

Comment: Side note, I'd better say `OVER( ..ORDER BY TransactionDate)` For a reason, some day `ID` ordering may differ from `TransactionDate`.

Comment: @Serg You're absolutely correct.  And because of the nature of the point system's complexity, transaction dates and IDs don't have a direct correlation.  I was merely using this for simplicity, however you're totally correct - good observation.

Comment: Are you sure results for `[Employee Running Total]` is correct? `ORDER BY ` should not affect result of `SUM`

Comment: @MikhailLobanov `ORDER BY` definitely affects the results of `SUM` (or any aggregate function) when using `OVER`.  If I remove the `ORDER BY`, it gives the same value as [Employee Total Points].  If I include the `ORDER BY`, it gives the cumulative total up to the current record, which is desired.

Comment: @StanShaw I think cumulative total should be calculated as by order by + `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT`

Comment: @MikhailLobanov Yes, that is correct, however, `OVER` with `ORDER BY` achieves the same result.